# Что означает строчка и методы на ней

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[][] list = new int[10][10];
        int min = -2;
        int max = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
                list[i][j] = (int) (Math.round(Math.random()*((max-min)+1)));
                // ВОТ в ЭТОЙ ^ СТРОЧКЕ ЧТО делает КАЖДЫЙ метод Распишите пожалуйста.
                    System.out.print(list[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Задавайте вопросы по одному. Укажите метод, который Вам непонятен и поясните что именно вызывает сложности. В нынешнем виде вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Math.random()//(Math.random()*((max-min)+1))//(Math.round(Math.random()*((max-min)+1)))//(int) (Math.round(Math.random()*((max-min)+1)))

Comment: Вы бы хоть слово «пожалуйста» добавляли в свои вопросы, а то они звучат как требования.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пробегаетесь по каждой ячейке двумерного массива с целочисленными (`int`) элементами, затем в каждую ячейку записываете приведённый к целочисленному типу результат округления произведения случайного double значения с положительным знаком, которое больше чем или равно 0.0 и меньше чем 1.0 на случайное число из диапазона `min-max+1`. Спасибо, кэп.

Если всё таки пробежаться по всей строчке, о которой вы просите (и что, вы планируете что впредь всё будут вам по буковке разжёвывать?), то:

```
list[i][j] =           // присваиваем очередной ячейке двумерного массива
(int)                  // приводим тип к int (то, что будет передано дальше)
 (
  Math.round(          // округляем переданный аргумент до ближайшего целого числа
    Math.random()      // генерируем случайное double число от 0.0 до 1.0
   *                   // умножаем
    ((max - min) + 1)  // вычисляем диапазон
  )
 );
```